# Recreate image after unzipping word to get them

Tags: python, image, ms-word, zip

I have a word file that has no text but images which are not inline. I have used `zipfile` to obtain all the images presented in my document, but instead of getting two images (one per page). I am getting a total of 53 items, which all are part of the bigger image. To do so, I have used the following code:

```
import zipfile

z = zipfile.ZipFile(word_filepath)
all_files =  z.namelist()
images = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('word/media/'), all_files))

for i, image in enumerate(images):
    image = z.open(image).read()
    with open(f'savepath/{i}.png', 'wb') as f: 
        f.write(image)
```

Is there a way to reconstruct the bigger image out of the small ones? So I would have as many pngs as pages my document has.

Comment: Have you inspected the underlying Word Open XML and the ZIP files to see how Word is handling this, behind the scenes? Is there something special/unusual about these image files? Can you provide steps to reproduce how the Word document was created with these images?

Comment: I have no clue how the word document was created as I only received it, I haven't created it... Abput the underlying XML yes I did and there's a main graphic ``<a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">`` inside which there are the other pics.

Comment: It might help if you edit the question to include the relevant Word Open XML (and I mean also the "inside which").